# CSS Fixed header of unknown height

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a header fixed to the top of the page that can wrap creating more height when the page is resized to a smaller width.

How do I make the the page content (#wrapper) always begin at the bottom of the header with CSS only?

```
<body>
 <header>
  This fixed content will wrap on small devices.
 </header>
 <div id="wrapper">
  This content should always begin immediately below the header.
 </div>
<body>
```

Comment: you can remove the `position:fixed` from the header in '@media' queries for the resolution and change it to `position:relative`

Comment: You can't make `position: fixed` elements interact with others in the page. It is not part of the page anymore.... Either make it not fixed, or give it a fixed height...

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes That's a good idea but the header needs to remain fixed on small screens too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

...As already stated in the comments above, you have to use a JS solution, unless you are able to know at which resolutions the fixed header's height increases in which case you can use media queries and either use padding-top for the #wrapper element equal to the fixed header's height, or use an empty element with height equal to the header's.

Answer (score 2):

As you only want to use CSS, you could just set `padding-top` on your `#wrapper` div so it moves the content below the bottom of the header. Then adjust the `padding-top` size for each screen size in media queries.

Comment: I think a JS solution looks like the only way to do it. Set the top padding of wrapper depending on the height of the the header. I was really looking for a CSS only way though.

Comment: I would suggest you suing a fixed height for the header when you get to a mobile view and set a margin-top on your #wrapper. There is only a limited space on mobile and it would be a shame to waste alot of it on a header. You should ensure the content that is important on mobile does not suffer because of less important elements.

Comment: That's what I was doing and it was fine. However, I've added an extra bar to the top of the header when a user has not verified their email address. The text is quite long and it wraps on tablet and mobile views.

Comment: Actually, I think I'll add the verification message the top of the content inside #wrapper on small screen devices.

Comment: Does this extra bar have a fixed height? If so you could do a simple conditional statement to see if the email address is not verified, and set the margin-top accordingly whether the email is or is not verified, adding and subtracting the height of the extra bar you are using.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62350/discussion-between-asa-carter-and-alan).

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to change the HTML, then another approach that avoids the use of JavaScript is to include two copies of the header element:

```
<body>
 <header id="show">
  This fixed content will wrap on small devices.
 </header>
 <header id="flow">
  This fixed content will wrap on small devices.
 </header>
 <div id="wrapper">
  This content should always begin immediately below the header.
 </div>
<body>
```

Then you can use `#show { position: fixed; zIndex: 10000 }` for the first element (to keep the header visible), and `#flow { display: hidden }` on the second element to consume the space in the page flow.